# C++ WriteProcessMemory error INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm using to the "CreateRemoteThread & WriteProcessMemory" Technique to inject my dll into another process. My code work fine on windows 7,8, but WriteProcessMemory function always return FALSE (GetLastError = 6 - INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) when run on windows XP (VirtualBox machine). Can't u help me?
Here is the main code:

```
BOOL CHookDLL::DoHook(const DWORD dwProcessId, const CHAR* szDLLHookName)
{
    CHAR    szDllHookPath[1024] = "";
    HANDLE  hRemoteThread = NULL;
    HMODULE hLib = 0;
    LPVOID  RemoteString = NULL;
    LPVOID  LoadLibAddy = NULL;

    if (dwProcessId == NULL){
        __OutputDebug("CHookDLL::DoHook\tpProcessId NULL");
        return FALSE;
    }

    ::GetFullPathNameA(szDLLHookName, MAX_PATH, szDllHookPath, NULL);
    if (::PathFileExists((CString)szDllHookPath) == FALSE){
        __OutputDebug("CHookDLL::DoHook\tPathFileExists FALSE");
        return FALSE;
    }

    // enable SeDebugPrivilege
    if (!SetPrivilege(m_hTokenSetPrivilege, SE_DEBUG_NAME, TRUE))
    {
        __OutputDebug("CHookDLL::DoHook\tSetPrivilege FAILED");
        // close token handle
        CloseHandle(m_hTokenSetPrivilege);
        return FALSE;
    }
    m_hProcess = ::OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, dwProcessId);
    if (m_hProcess == NULL){
        __OutputDebug("CHookDLL::DoHook\tOpenProcess FALSE: %d", GetLastError());
        return FALSE;
    }

    LoadLibAddy = (LPVOID)::GetProcAddress(::GetModuleHandleA("kernel32.dll"), "LoadLibraryA");

    if (LoadLibAddy == NULL){
        __OutputDebug("CHookDLL::DoHook\tGetProcAddress NULL");
        return FALSE;
    }
    // Allocate space in the process for our DLL 
    RemoteString = (LPVOID)VirtualAllocEx(m_hProcess, NULL, strlen(szDllHookPath) + 1,
        MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);

    if (RemoteString == NULL){
        __OutputDebug("CHookDLL::DoHook\tVirtualAllocEx NULL");
        return FALSE;
    }

        // this line is return FALSE
    if (WriteProcessMemory(m_hProcess, RemoteString, szDllHookPath, strlen(szDllHookPath) + 1, NULL) == FALSE)
    {
        __OutputDebug("CHookDLL::DoHook\tWriteProcessMemory FALSE: %d", GetLastError());
        return FALSE;
    }

    hRemoteThread = ::CreateRemoteThread(m_hProcess, NULL, NULL,
        (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)LoadLibAddy,
        (LPVOID)RemoteString, NULL, NULL);

    ::WaitForSingleObject(hRemoteThread, INFINITE);

    // Get handle of the loaded module
    ::GetExitCodeThread(hRemoteThread, &m_hLibModule);
    if (m_hLibModule == NULL){
        __OutputDebug("CHookDLL::DoHook\tCreateRemoteThread NULL");
        return FALSE;
    }
    // Clean up
    ::CloseHandle(hRemoteThread);
    ::VirtualFreeEx(m_hProcess, RemoteString,
        strlen(szDllHookPath) + 1, MEM_RELEASE);

    __OutputDebug("Hook OK");
    return TRUE;
}

// Common function Output Debug String
static INT __OutputDebug(const CHAR* format, ...)
{
#ifndef DEBUG
    return -1;
#endif // DEBUG

    if (format[0] == 0) return -1;

    CHAR szDebug[1024] = "";

    va_list arglist;
    va_start(arglist, format);
    vsprintf_s(szDebug,format, arglist);
    va_end(arglist);
    strcat_s(szDebug, "\n");

    OutputDebugStringA(szDebug);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: You've already verified that the handle is valid.  So you probably have broken error reporting, fumbling GetLastError() is a *very* common problem.  We can't see __OutputDebug, make sure it is not a macro.

Comment: Thank u comment. __OutputDebug just only  is common function to call API OutputDebugString. I just want fix why WriteProcessMemory return FALSE. What about u think? Please give me u ideas. Thank u.

Comment: I have post code of __OutputDebug in footer of question.

Comment: Well, that's not it.  Setting a data breakpoint on "m_hProcess" so you can see it being overwritten is all that's left that I can think of.

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies in your `OpenProcess` call. From here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684880(v=vs.85).aspx, listed under `PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS` access right:

> Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP:  The size of the PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS flag increased on Windows Server 2008 and Windows Vista. If an application compiled for Windows Server 2008 and Windows Vista is run on Windows Server 2003 or Windows XP, the PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS flag is too large and the function specifying this flag fails with ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED. To avoid this problem, specify the minimum set of access rights required for the operation. If PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS must be used, set _WIN32_WINNT to the minimum operating system targeted by your application (for example, #define _WIN32_WINNT _WIN32_WINNT_WINXP). For more information, see Using the Windows Headers.

Therefore, it may be that `PROCESS_VM_READ` and `PROCESS_VM_OPERATION` aren't getting set, hence the invalid handle error later on. I know that that `OpenProcess` should really be returning an error code if it fails - and it's not - but if this flag is genuinely overflowing, I can see how a silent failure might occur.